how to use a custom class with dependancy injection and segue
I've recently started with dependancy injections in swift and i cant figure out how to pass a custom class while segueing to another Viewcontroller.
class Content {
    var title:String
    var about:String
    var location:String

    init(data: [String: Any]) {
        self.title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
        self.about = data["about"] as? String ?? ""
        self.location = data["location"] as? String ?? "" 
    }
}


First Viewcontroller - Performing segue and passing necessary data.
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "NextView", sender: self.allcontent[indexPath.item])
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "NextView" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! NextViewController
        let selectedRow = sender as? Content
            
        vc.content = selectedRow!
           
    }
}

Attempting to initiate NextViewcontroller with the passed custom class from the first ViewController.
class NextViewController: UIViewController {
    var content: Content
    
    init(content: Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    // this way i can access properties from the custom class directly
    //content.title
    //content.about
}

I keep getting different warnings as i'm not sure on how to structure this correctly.

'super.init' isn't called on all paths before returning from initializer
'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'UIViewController'

I've seen below code implemented in an example but i don't understand what "coder" is or how its supposed to be used.
class EditUserViewController: UIViewController {
    var selectedUser: User

    init?(coder: NSCoder, selectedUser: User) {
        self.selectedUser = selectedUser
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("You must create this view controller with a user.")
    }

    // ...
}

Any help or example would be appreciated.

Just remove init(content: Content)or init?(coder: NSCoder, selectedUser: User) and it should just work. And use var content: Content? or var content: Content! (it might depend then on how "safe you are using the VC"...

It looks at first blush as if true dependency injection is impossible, because:

You want NextViewController's content property to be not an Optional; but

If NextViewController is instantiated from a segue, it must be instantiated via init(coder:) and there is no way to supply the content.


Well, anyone who tells you that true dependency injection is impossible in this situation is just wrong. (For example, Paulw11's "You cannot use a custom initialiser when you are using segues" is simply false.) The solution is to use an IBSegueAction. It was invented (by Apple) to handle exactly this situation.

To illustrate, I will simplify. Start like this. Here is ViewController; it has a button which, like your collection view cell, is supposed to trigger the segue when tapped:
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func doButton (_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "nextViewControllerSegue", sender: self)
    }
}

And here is NextViewController, where it appears, at first blush, as though all is lost, because content is not an Optional (I have simplified Content too):
struct Content {
    var title: String
}

class NextViewController: UIViewController {
    var content: Content

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(self.content)
    }
}

Even though it appears that we are at an impasse, I will show, in three simple steps, how to solve the problem.
Step one: Give NextViewController another initializer. It must take an NSCoder, but it can take any other parameters you desire. With the NSCoder, you must call super's implementation of init(coder:). The other parameters, obviously, constitute our chance to inject a Content object:
init?(coder: NSCoder, content: Content) {
    self.content = content
    super.init(coder: coder)
}

Step two: Give the first view controller, which I call ViewController, an IBSegueAction function. This is a function marked @IBSegueAction and taking an NSCoder, and returning a UIViewController, which it must instantiate by means of the given NSCoder. This is where we are going to call the initializer that we created in the previous step! Ready? Here we go...!
@IBSegueAction func createNextViewController(coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController? {
    return NextViewController(
        coder: coder, 
        content: Content(title: "Howdy")
    )
}

Do you see the dependency injection there? In real life, you would somehow fetch the desired Content object from a stored property of ViewController, or construct in any desired fashion (as I have done here), and pass it as the content parameter to that initializer.
Step three: Finally (and I'm afraid I cannot show you this step), in the storyboard, select the segue from ViewController to NextViewController, switch to the Connections inspector, and drag from the empty circle next to "instantiation" to ViewController and, in the HUD that appears, select createNextViewControllerWithCoder.

Done! When performSegue is called, createNextViewController is called, NextViewController is created from the storyboard in good order, the Content is injected, the segue is performed, and viewDidLoad reports that everything worked correctly.

I have put the demonstration project at https://github.com/mattneub/SegueActionDemo so you can download it and try it and examine it and understand it.
